# Error: 'TextInputControl' flutter zefyrka package

Tags: flutter, package, issue-tracking

i get this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../development/sdks/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zefyrka-1.4.0/lib/src/widgets/editor.dart:1321:7: Error: Type 'TextInputControl' not found.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../development/sdks/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zefyrka-1.4.0/lib/src/widgets/editor.dart:1321:37: Error: Type 'TextInputControl' not found.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../development/sdks/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zefyrka-1.4.0/lib/src/widgets/editor.dart:1321:7: Error: 'TextInputControl' isn't a type.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../development/sdks/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zefyrka-1.4.0/lib/src/widgets/editor.dart:1321:37: Error: 'TextInputControl' isn't a type.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and this happens after remove the zefrka package and reuse it

what is problem?